Cant figure this out
Below circuit pulled from homemade-circuit.com,
Practical Voltage Regulator Project with Feedback for Enhancing Output Accuracy,
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/simple-voltage-regulator-circuits-using-transistor-and-zener-diode/
Can an expert here tell me how this circuit work and initial and steady state currents voltages thru transistors, its base its collector and its emittor and resistors?  Detail analysis of the circuit


You can enter the circuit into an online simulator that will answer the voltage and current questions. The circuit is a classic series pass regulator with current limiting. Q1 is the current limit with R5 setting the limit value. R3 and D1 form the voltage reference with Q3 being the difference amp to drive Q2 which is the series pass device. I am suspicious of this actual circuit so you might want to find a better source for your reference.

I dont want answer.  My question is how you get those answers about voltage and current questions

Simulation shows that it regulates at about 16.75V with 24V in and current limits at about 620mA.
With 16V in, the output voltage drops from about 14.5V to 9.5V as the current increases from 0 to 500mA.
The 1N757 is a 9.1V zener diode, and the (back of envelope) voltage at which is regulates would be expected to be that, plus 0.7V multiplied by 1.68 or 16.46V.
This agrees reasonably well with the simulation, however the Zener diode is dissipating more than its rated power with 24V in.
The current limit is estimated to be roughly one diode drop across 1.5Ω or 460mA (not very accurate because the voltage through the diodes is rather high at 60mA or so with 24V in).
There are two parts to this circuit- the basic series regulator which consists of this circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Below the regulated output, the circuit is an emitter follower. When the divided output voltage reaches the zener voltage plus the e-b drop of about 0.7 V then the small transistor turns on and steals base current from the TIP42 to more-or-less maintain the output voltage.
The rest of the circuit is a current limit that also limits the base current when the output current causes the voltage across the 1.5Ω resistor to be more than one diode drop, thus turning the PNP transistor off.
If we assume the output current is supposed to be limited to 500mA then we can calculate the minimum input voltage of the circuit. The TIP41A has a minimum gain of 30 at 25°C and 300mA. Should be similar at 500mA. Typical is more like 100. Let's assume a 13.2V output voltage even though we know that is wrong.
So at 500mA we need 17V (worst-case) across the 1kΩ resistor or 5.5V (typical). More at low temperature. Plus 0.7V for the transistor base and 0.75V for the 1.5Ω resistor. Call it 1.5V, so 18.5V to 7V.
So for 13.2V out we need between 31.7V (worst-case at room temperature) to 20.2V (typical) input voltage.
With the 16.5V or so output voltage that this circuit typically regulates at, the minimum input voltage for regulation with 0.5A out is typically 23 volts.
Worst case, is much, much higher.
So the circuit will not produce the specified output voltage, will not regulate over the range specified (even typically) and is going to overheat the zener diode, but it does (very roughly) function. They did not specify the output current so that is not possible to evaluate.
If the output is shorted, the short-circuit protection will limit the current, however the dissipation in the output transistor will be very high and without a quite large heat sink the transistor will fail, since there is no thermal protection. It's possible Q3 will be damaged in short-circuit conditions because the E-B junction will experience reverse breakdown (the maximum Veb is 6V and it will see more than 9V).
A much better circuit would be something like this:

simulate this circuit
Or you can use an LM317 with a couple resistors.

The 2 diodes and R3 bias the zener. When the V at VOUT raises the V at the R divider to 0.7 V above this, Q3 turns on and shunts base current away from Q2.
This base current was supplied by Q1 and R4. Q1 is on until the I*R drop across R 5 exceeds 0.7 V when it will turn off and stop supplying base current to Q2. Thus this is a current limit function.
